# Android mp3 analysis

Tags: android, fft, business-process-management

I'm making a music player for android and I would like to get the average BPM (maybe also frequencies or tones) of a song BEFORE playing it, so I can show the user some info about the song, I know I probably have to open a stream and apply some maths to it to get the data I need, but I don't know how to act, can anyone help me?

Comment: Not a real answer but a step in the right direction: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen that and I know that Visualizer can perform a ffT on a input, another problem is... which input?

Comment: I've seen an example using android.media.MediaPlayer and creating the visualizer like this: new Visualizer(mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId()); but I thinks that means you have to play the music.

Comment: Yes, with that method you have to, I just wonder how can I process a song without playing it, if I can achieve this maybe I could apply the fft to the song, don't know :\

Comment: Maybe you can use MediaPlayer#setVolume and then process the songs 1 by 1

Comment: Well but then the user would have to wait lots of time, I'm looking for a way to process it in an "instant"

Comment: Are we talking about PCM/WAV music or something compressed like MP3? To process compressed audio, you'll have to convert it to PCM. I can tell you(from painful experience) that "instant" MP3 decoding isn't possible. There are several libraries to do it(like JLayer for java, or ffmpeg for native), but none are instant. I don't have benchmarks for ffmpeg, but using JLayer, an average 3 minute VBR MP3 takes between 15-45 seconds, depending on hardware. Once you have the data, calculating BPM and doing the FFT hardly take any time at all.

Comment: Yes, I am playing MP3 files.
But if I can't process them without listening to them, how can I do?
The user must completely listen to a song?
Is there any trick I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution!
I'm using the Minim java audio library, which can performs offline analysis on the audio buffer :)
http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/manual-minim/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FFT

[FFT library in android Sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272232/fft-library-in-android-sdk)

This example may be helpful:

[Android audio FFT to retrieve specific frequency magnitude using audiorecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774104/android-audio-fft-to-retrieve-specific-frequency-magnitude-using-audiorecord)

another one:

[Get sound frequency with Android FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325123/i-want-get-frequency-using-android-fft)

Comment: Yes, those are useful, but I need to find a way to get all the mp3 data at once, without listening to the song :\

Comment: Maybe I could gather data while the song is being played and then process them at the end of the song!