# How to get the volume of a playing song continuously?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

Well, I want to build an android app that when I playing a song with a music player. listen to the volume of the current song continuously, and show it on the screen .

I have read the manuals of MediaPlayer, MediaRecorder, AudioTrack, AudioRecorder from sdk. But it seems none of them meets my need.

Could any one give me a hint?

Edit:

I want to analyze the song to know the saturation level, not the system volume.

Comment: Do you want to know the system volume level or analyze the song to know the saturation level?

Comment: Sounds like something you could do with [the Visualizer API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html).

Answer (score 0):

have you try this :

```
value = audioManager.getStreamVolume(audioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

and this is the info link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

Answer (score 0):

**Found this (interesting!):**

http://netscale.cse.nd.edu/twiki/pub/Main/Projects/Analyze_the_frequency_and_strength_of_sound_in_Android.pdf

**and look at:**

http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/manual-minim/

There are a lot answers can help you with your idea:

[Android audio FFT to retrieve specific frequency magnitude using audiorecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774104/android-audio-fft-to-retrieve-specific-frequency-magnitude-using-audiorecord)

[Get sound frequency with Android FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325123/i-want-get-frequency-using-android-fft)